# PHP/JQuery - Disable button when "U" is typed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to disable this button when the "U" word pops up. how can i do this?

p.s. U is defined as Unable

here is my button

```
  <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-warning" name="search" value="Search Data"></input>
```

here is my **MODAL** **EDIT**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                The User is Inactive
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Please try another active users, Thanks!
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
            <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Tamam</a>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my code and jquery inside

```
  <input type="text" name="txtstatus" value="<?php echo $row['status'] ?>" class="validate form-control" id="soluong">


                    <?php 

                      if($row['status'] == 'U'){
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                          $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("soluong").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                          });
                       </script>

                      }

                     ?>
```

Comment: `php` is a server-side language and executed on the server before any `javascript`. I am sure you can accomplish this without the need of `php`. You can check the input on page load and you can check it on `change` / `input`

Comment: @NewToJS But i need the statement. if I remove it inside the `if` statement and place it outside the `php` then it will disable automatically i cannot do this because if the "U" is typed in then it is disabled.

Comment: This is why I said check the input on page load and using an event listener like `change/input` will deal with changes to that input after.

Comment: how can i do it with the code?  im confused :( sorry

Comment: Maybe this [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pqm9shr5/) might be of some help? As you can see the input contains the word "val**u**e" if you edit that it will enable the button again unless you then type "u" which will then disable it again. If the `php` adds a value that does not contain `U` it will be enabled  as you can see form this [**Minor JsFiddle Edit**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pqm9shr5/2/)

Comment: @NewToJS , hey sir, I've tried your logic i remove the `php` and put `javascript` instead but it did not work

Comment: @NewToJS hey sir, It worked!!!!! thanks

Comment: Very welcome, if you have any questions about the demo provided please feel free to ask and I will try answer/explain the best I can.

Comment: @NewToJS hey sir, please provide an answer below so i can marked it as an anaswer but before lastly how can i show my modal after disabled

Comment: I am writing one up as we speak. I would like to be sure I provide the relevant details of my changes and the reason(s) for them.

Comment: @NewToJS hey sir i've edited my code above pls see my modal how can i popup that when the button has been disabled thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that leads to a new question.

Comment: @NewToJS :(  why sir :(

Comment: Because you wanted to know how to *"Disable button when “U” is typed"* but extending the question after being provided with a solution is then creating a new question but here it a potability. You could add  `$("#confirm-submit").css("display", 'none');` but remember this will execute when the input changes. [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pqm9shr5/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` is a server-side language and executed on the server before any `javascript`

You can check the input value on page load and on change/input events.

In my answer I have created a function `DisableBtn()` to deal with validating the input and enabling/disabling the button. This function will be called on DOM ready and when the `input` event is triggered.

I have also used `toLowerCase()` to ensure this will work for both lower and uppercase characters.

`indexOf('u') > -1` is used to check if the value contains a specific. **False:** `-1`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function DisableBtn() {
    if ($("#soluong").val().toLowerCase().indexOf('u') > -1) {
      $("#MyBtn").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#MyBtn").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
  DisableBtn();
  $('#soluong').on('input', DisableBtn);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="soluong" value="Value" />
<input type="submit" id="MyBtn" value="Search Data" />
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I well get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: sir i edited the code above as for my modal please help me on how to show it after disabled thanks

Comment: @obitouchiha You wanted to know how to *"Disable button when “U” is typed"* but extending the question after being provided with a solution is then creating a new question but here it a potability. You could add  `$("#confirm-submit").css("display", 'none');` but remember this will execute when the input changes. [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pqm9shr5/8/)

Comment: @obitouchiha I have gone one step further than usual and I am not 100% sure this is what you are looking for but maybe this is what you are asking for? [**Final JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/pqm9shr5/16/)

Comment: sir dont worry your first JsFiddle works i just designed it ! you are truly a svior thanks sir

Comment: i found a modal with css so your first fiddle works i just forgot to reply because im rushing time sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `indexOf` it looks for instance of a character in string. When found it returns index if not return -1

```js
var data = 'Unable';

if(data.indexOf('U')==-1){
alert('not found')
}else{
alert('found')

}
```

Comment: that seems to work but how can I implement this on my textbox ? `txtstatus` ?  it seems it is automatically without specifying my text box

Comment: sir it is working but even tho the "U" is not found it has an alert saying `found`

Comment: try the demo remove U it will not say found. can you update your OP with what you tried